# How to optimize objective in the Grassmann manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, grassmannian, stiefel-manifolds

For Stiefel manifold, it contains all the orthogonal column matrices

$$St(d,M) = \{X \in R^{M \times d} | X^TX = I\}$$

For Grassmann manifold, it is 
$$Gr(d,M) = \{col(X), X \in R^{M \times d}\}$$

For an objective problem
$$ \min_{X \in St(d,M)} f(X)$$

can we solve above optimization using 
$$ \min_{X \in Gr(d,M)} f(X)$$

Is above transform legal? or $f(X)$ should satisfy some conditions?

Comment: Yes. The Stiefel manifold is an $O(n)$ principle bundle over the Grassman manifold.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold#As_a_principal_bundle  ... for information on principle bundles these notes are good: https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/18.906/prin.pdf

Comment: I add some note above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $d\leq M$ and we work over $\mathbb{R}$. Your definition of $Gr$ is false; the $X$ must have full rank.  On the other hand, it's not a good parametrization; you must add the quotient by the equivalence relation: $X\sim X'$ if and only if $X'=Xh$ where $h\in GL_d$.

Consider the canonical functions

$$f:O(M)\rightarrow St(d,M),g:O(M)\rightarrow Gr(d,M),h:St(d,M)\rightarrow Gr(d,m).$$

Since $f$, $g$, and $h$ are submersions, we deduce that

\begin{align}
St(d,M)
&\sim O(M)/O(M-d),Gr(d,M) \\
&\sim St(d,M)/O(d) \\
&\sim O(M)/(O(d)\times O(M-d)).\end{align}

Note also that $Gr(d,M)\sim Gr(M-d,M)$ and have dimension $d(M-d)$.

EDIT. Answer to OP. The problems 
$$\min_{U\in St(d,N)}\langle UU^T,L\rangle+\beta \|UU^T\|_1$$
and 
$$\min_{U\in Gr(d,N)}\langle  UU^T,L\rangle+\beta \|UU^T\|_1$$
are equivalent under the condition that a representative of $U\in Gr$ is one of its orthonormal bases.